# Is there a cross browser solution for performance.now() in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Google Chrome added support for `performance.now()` to provide more precise timing. Is there any cross browser support for higher precision timers? If so, what are the respective examples?

More about `performance.now()` https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/When-milliseconds-are-not-enough-performance-now

Comment: Firefox also supports `window.performance.now()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes, but vendor specific prefixes must be addressed. Here is a shim that summarizes.

```
var performance = window.performance || {};
performance.now = (function() {
  var _now = Date.now();
  return performance.now    ||
  performance.webkitNow     ||
  performance.msNow         ||
  performance.oNow          ||
  performance.mozNow        ||
  function() { return Date.now() - _now; };
})();
```

This shim is based upon examples in the gists.

- https://gist.github.com/davidwaterston/2982531
- https://gist.github.com/JordanDelcros/30845e2dbc0b21ac0869